# Cannot read property 'addEventListener'

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una ejercicio de **simulación básica de cajero**.

me da el siguiente error al momento de ejecutar el código, no he podido encontrar el error.

> Cannot read property 'addEventListener'

Agradeceré mucho su orientación,
Gracias!

**JS**:

```
class billete{
constructor(v,c){
    this.valor=v;
    this.cantidad=c;
}
}
function entregarDinero()
{
for(var bi of caja)
{
    console.log(bi);
}
}

var caja=[];
var entregado=[];
caja.push(new billete(50,3));
caja.push(new billete(20,2));
caja.push(new billete(10,2));

var dinero=210;
var div=0;
var papeles=0;

var b=document.getElementById("extraer");
b.addEventListener("click", entregarDinero);
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cajero</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Mi primer cajero!</h1>
<p> wow! :O </p>
<img src="cajero.webp">
</br>
<script src="cajero.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="dinero">
 <input type="button" value="Extraer" id="extraer" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A mi me funciona bien tu codigo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He probado tu código y es totalmente funcional, el único detalle que pudieras tener es donde estas escribiendo el JS; te comento que tu código debería tener este orden

**INDICACIONES**

> 1.- Donde como puedes notar primero hago la declaración del HTML
>   2.- Después escribo el JS, por que si hago la lógica antes, entonces la sentencia donde obtienes al botón por su id, nunca lo va a
>   encontrar por que en ese momento aún no existe en el árbol DOM
>   3.- El error `Cannot read property 'addEventListener'` es por que cuando se ejecuta ese bloque de código aun no existe ese nodo,
>   entonces lo mas seguro es que tienes primero el JS y luego el HTML
>   declarado

**CÓDIGO FUNCIONAL**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cajero</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Mi primer cajero!</h1>
<p> wow! :O </p>
<img src="cajero.webp">
</br>
<script src="cajero.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="dinero">
 <input type="button" value="Extraer" id="extraer" />
</body>
<script>
class billete{
constructor(v,c){
    this.valor=v;
    this.cantidad=c;
}
}
function entregarDinero()
{
for(var bi of caja)
{
    console.log(bi);
}
}

var caja=[];
var entregado=[];
caja.push(new billete(50,3));
caja.push(new billete(20,2));
caja.push(new billete(10,2));

var dinero=210;
var div=0;
var papeles=0;

var b=document.getElementById("extraer");
b.addEventListener("click", entregarDinero);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, ya me estaba inventando teorías raras, pensaba que era por el evento onload, algo así como que era un void o constructor, para crear eventos se tenia que anidar, Tenías razón solo era cambiar el linck al final del boddy, un error muy de novato (ya me había pasado y se me olvido)